# Disable the dictionary by default automatic

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython

```
    import collections.OrderedDict 
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    r = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLIeGtxpvyG-JI5RDHtjk0NtyQPirBfBpu')
    r.status_code
    if  r.status_code == 200 :
        soup = BeautifulSoup (r.text,'html.parser')

    OrderedDict.dict = {}
    for i in soup.findAll('td',{'class':'pl-video-title'}):
        #print i 
        dict [i.find('a').text] = i.findAll('td' , { 'class': "pl-video-time"})[0].text

for i,k in collections.OrderedDict.dict.items():
    print i, k
```

I was able to run the program successfully but I want retain the same order. I want to know how to use 'OrderedDict' module in my case. If I use 'OrderedDict' module i'm getting an error.

Comment: Firstly, what is your error?  Could you include that and the full traceback?  Secondly, `import collections.OrderedDict` is not how you import the `OrderedDict`.  It is not a module, it is a class in the the `collections` module.   Instead do `from collections import OrderedDict`.  To create an `OrderedDict` do `my_od = OrderedDict()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLIeGtxpvyG-JI5RDHtjk0NtyQPirBfBpu')

if r.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

    d = OrderedDict()
    for i in soup.findAll('td', {'class': 'pl-video-title'}):
        d[i.find('a').text] = i.findAll('td', {'class': "pl-video-time"})[0].text

    for i, k in d.items():
        print i, k
```

First of all, you have to to import OrderedDict from the collections module.

I removed the dangling r.status_code since it's not doing anything, then put everything inside the if r.status_code == 200, otherwise you'd get a NameError exception, I also changed dict to d, since you'd be shadowing that variable, besides that I fixed the formatting a bit.

Answer (score 0):

to instantiate an OrderedDict you have to do

```
myOrderedDict = OrderedDict([])
```

not

```
OrderedDict.dict = {}
```

and to iterate through the ordered dict it'd be

```
for i,j in in myOrderedDict.items():
    #do something with i and j
```

Comment: His import is messed up, so you might want to include that in your answer.

Comment: If he wants to "override" dict then he should write dict = OrderedDict. If not, he should not write dict = OrderedDict() either